# Define Kubernetes Custom Resource requiring one of the following fields or no fields

Tags: kubernetes, openapi, kubernetes-custom-resources

I try to define a new Custom Resource, requiring it to have one of (1) field A, (2) field B, or (3) empty body.

For example: {A: 1}, {B: 1}, {} are OK, but {A:1, B:2} is not.

Here is the definition of my Custom Resource in form of OpenApi schema:

```yaml
foo:
  type: object
  properties:
    a:
     type: int
    b:
     type: int
  oneOf:
    - required: ["a"]
    - required: ["b"]
    # no sure how to include the empty body
```

How should I include the empty body in the oneOf constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OpenAPI 3.1

You can use `'null'` (with quotes).

```
oneOf:
  - type: 'null'
```

Or an object with a property of type null.

```
oneOf:
  - NullObjectExample:
    type: object
    properties:
      prop1:
        type: 'null'
```

### OpenAPI 3.0

There is no `null` type, but you can use a `nullable` string. You may want to add a `description` stating this is expected to be null at all times.

```
oneOf:
  - type: string
    nullable: true
```

Or again, an object with a nullable string property.

```
oneOf:
  - NullObjectExample:
    type: object
    properties:
      prop1:
        type: string
        nullable: true
```

### Why No Empty Object

In addition to not making intent clear, this presents a possible security vulnerability. See [this page](https://apisecurity.io/encyclopedia/content/oasv2/datavalidation/schema/schema-object-without-properties) for an explanation. In short:

> If you do not clearly define the schema and you leave properties of a JSON payload empty, you effectively allow attackers to pass in any data. This means that you are opening your backend to various attacks, such as SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would prefer an empty structure like {}, rather than null. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can have an object with a null property. Added examples.